# Delete all instances of red text in adobe acrobat

Tags: pdf, acrobat

A client has provided a several pdf documents, each over 300+ pages.

They marked up the document by adding text boxes to each page. We can identify what they added easily because their additions are in red font. We would like to identify any text boxes that have red font in order to delete them from the document, thereby leaving a document that does not include their additions.

I have been able to click on the text and delete it manually but that only allows us to do one at a time. I have checked the ActionWizard menu, the redaction functionality, the search function and the sanitize function but these do not appear to address this issue as needed. Is there any way to delete all instances of red (or any specific color) text?

I would also like to clarify that in some instances they included CIRCLES from the drawing tool menu, again these would be in red. We would also like to remove those from the document.

We are using Adobe Acrobat Pro XI but are open to any solutions.

Comment: Is the text added as free text comments? By your description, that's what it sounds like.

Comment: Correct, it seems that they just used the "Add Text" option in the content editing menu.

Comment: I have the same problem...